# Why is the minimum value of macro : RAND_MAX , 32767

Tags: c++, macros

This [website](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/RAND_MAX/) states that the value of the macro `RAND_MAX` is library-dependent and the minimum value is 32767. It does not elaborate further.

1. What does library dependent mean ?? Does this mean assuming there are two macros `RAND_MAX` from two different library , we have to differentiate them by using different namespaces ??
2. Why is the minimum value of `RAND_MAX` 32767

Comment: There isn't just one standard library implementation, there's libstdc++, libc++, STLPort, Dinkumware's Microsoft one.

Comment: If you're working with random numbers you may want to look at C++11's [random number library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: @chris: `RAND_MAX` is inherited from the C library, so the list is msvcrt, msvcr*, glibc, ulibc, bionic, etc... The C++ library implementation will have very little to do with any of it.

Comment: Although RAND_MAX is 32767, the operations with most libraries are 32 bit operations, with the result being shifted right and masked to 16 bits. Wiki article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means there are different implementations of the standard library, and each is allowed to define RAND_MAX differently, though it must always be at least 32767.

Namespaces don't get involved, because RAND_MAX is a macro that doesn't live in a namespace. In any case, you normally only link with one standard library at a time. It typically ships with the compiler, and you just use it. You could have some other random number generator from some other library, but it should normally use something *other* than RAND_MAX to indicate the largest value it can/will create. In particular, if your compiler includes it, you probably want to use C++'s new "native" random number generation classes (see docs for `<rand>` for details).

32767 is the minimum primarily because that's the minimum value of INT_MAX. On 16-bit implementations (still common when the C89 standard was written) that was the largest signed integer those implementations could work with conveniently.

Comment: Beat me to the answer, +1.

Comment: standard library as in <cstdlib> ??

Comment: @Computernerd: Not exactly. "The standard library" includes the implementation of all the functions, macros, etc., in all the standard headers. Some of that will be in the headers themselves, other parts in statically or dynamically linked librarys (DLLs, .so's, etc.)

Comment: But in this case, `rand` is indeed defined in `<stdlib.h>` (C) / `<cstdlib>` (C++). The definition is rather weak: *The rand function computes a sequence of pseudo-random integers in the range 0 to RAND_MAX.* What's a pseudo-random integer? The standard doesn't say. Would an implementation of `rand` that always returns 42 pass muster? It's interesting that C++11 broke with the longstanding tradition of not specifying implementations. C++11 specifically dictates that a conforming implementation must provide an implementation of the Mersenne Twister algorithm to generate pseudo-random numbers.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Sometimes things take a while to come to fruition. As far as I know, I was the first to suggest mandating specific algorithms for random number generation--in a thread on comp.std.c, around 1995 or so.

Comment: @JerryCoffin - But you have to admit that calling out a specific implementation is a bit of a punt, and also goes against the grain of good requirementese. MT was a good algorithm circa 2000. Nowadays, there are algorithms that are arguably better. Being overly specific is a double edged sword. Compare `std::map`, where the standard goes out of the way of not calling out a red-black tree. This allows an implementation to use some new self-balancing tree algorithm that provides better performance than does a red-black tree.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Yes, I do realize that (and said so when I first suggested it). At the time I outlined the three possibilities I saw: leave things alone, mandate specific algorithms, or mandate specific tests that need to be passed. Of those three choices, specific algorithms seemed like the least problematic possibility.

Answer (score 1):

> What does library dependent mean?

It means that different implementations of the standard library can choose different values if they like. A larger value would give higher quality pseudo-randomness; but might be less efficient, especially on the steam-powered processors in common use when the C library was developed.

> Does this mean assuming there are two macros `RAND_MAX` from two different library , we have to differentiate them by using different namespaces?

You'll only be using one implementation of the standard library. If you were trying to use two for some reason, then you'll be in trouble with any macros, since they can't be contained by namespaces.

> Why is the minimum value of `RAND_MAX` 32767?

It's a fairly arbitrary limit, intended to allow an efficient (but low quality) implementation on a 16-bit processor.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's related to being stored on 16 bits (signed short).

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that the standard only requires that `RAND_MAX` has that minimum value, which we can see from the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) which the C++ standard falls back on for this case. In section `7.20.2.1` *The rand function* it says:

> The value of the RAND_MAX macro shall be at least 32767.

As to why the C99 draft standard assures that `INT_MAX` is at least `32767`.

There are many standard C++ libraries available [libstdc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/libstdc++/) and [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) being two of them and each one of them can have different values for `RAND_MAX` and still comply to the standard as long as it is at least `32767`.